# Can I disable commands in neo4j?

Tags: neo4j, cypher

Is there any way to disable some commands in neo4j?

To be specific, I have a database which serves for more people. And I would like to forbid commands which removes something from database (E.g. DELETE, REMOVE...). Therefore, if user JohnDoe tries to remove node, it won't be permitted.

If there isn't direct support for this, is there some kind of workaround?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Enterprise Edition of neo4j supports several [native roles](https://neo4j.com/docs/operations-manual/3.4/security/authentication-authorization/native-user-role-management/native-roles/), including the `reader` role -- which prevents a user with that role from writing to the DB.

*The "Native roles" are not supported in the Community Edition.*